# Python modules not working

Tags: c#, python, ironpython, nao-robot

I'm currently writing a C# App which should use a Python script for some tasks.

I have some modules in my Python "site-packages" folder for controlling an Alebaran NAO robot, and copied them to the IronPython "site-packages" folder. But when I try to import the naoqi file, it says:

```
No module named _inaoqi
```

There is an _inaoqi.pyd in the folder, too.

Anybody any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IronPython doesn't support CPython's .pyd files, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Is the **site-packages** folder in the python path?. Open a python interpreter and write:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

If the folder is not in the list you can add it following the instructions of this other answer: [How to add to the pythonpath in windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4855685/670873)

Comment: Yeah I put them in both paths (IronPython and Python).
I know what the problem is now (thanks to Aldebaran support):
The _inaoqi is written in C++, closed-source and linked with Python.lib from cPython. So it won't work from IronPython, which is in pure .Net.